# Code works on windows but not on mac

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, macos

I'm in the early stages of making Battleships (just started a computer science degree) and had been using Eclipse on Windows.  So far I've just created the grids and have added an actionlistener to the jbuttons so they change colour when clicked.

It works fine when I run it on my Windows PC, however when I try to run it on a mac, it just shows the basic grid and doesn't change colours or anything.

Anyone had a problem like this or can help? I can't figure out why it would work on one and not the other.

Thanks

Here is my code, if that helps (I know it's not elegant or anything right now)

```
public class BattleshipFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //creating JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battleship");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //creating User Panel
        JPanel userpanel = new JPanel();
        userpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        userpanel.setSize(400, 400);

        //creating JButton array
        JButton[] button = new JButton[100];

        //putting JButtons in User Panel
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            userpanel.add(button[i]);


            //changing colour of buttons when clicked
            button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    Object source = ev.getSource();
                    if (source instanceof Component) {
                        ((Component) source).setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //creating computer panel
        JPanel comppanel = new JPanel();
        comppanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        comppanel.setSize(400, 400);

        //putting JButtons in User Panel
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            comppanel.add(button[i]);


            //changing colour of buttons when clicked
            button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    Object source = ev.getSource();
                    if (source instanceof Component) {
                        ((Component) source).setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //creating menu panel
        JPanel menupanel = new JPanel();


        //creating buttons for menu
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        JButton load = new JButton("Load");

        save.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        load.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        //adding buttons to menu panel
        menupanel.add(save);
        menupanel.add(load);

        //adding panels into frame
        frame.add(userpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(menupanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(comppanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(2000, 1000);
    }

}
```

As I say, it works perfectly on my Windows Eclipse but not on Mac

Comment: Have you tried to do any debugging on the mac computer?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: For what it's worth, an array of buttons is probably a bad choice here; Try making the board your own subclass of JPanel. You can then attach mouse listeners to the component and get the clicks by using math on the x,y coordinates.